# Want to update other column field values based on the new edited value on my grid rally

Tags: extjs, extjs4, rally

I have a application which shows `grid`

When I edit a one field(salary), I want to update other column field values like `cost` based on the new edited value for `salary`.
So `cost` will be calculated as `salary` divided by no. of developers(Count)
I tried to do that, but not able to set value.

Any suggestions

Below is my code

```
            _getSpan: function(val) {
                return val;
            },
            _draw_grid: function(newHash, committedData) {
                acceptedPoints = {};
                Ext.Array.each(committedData, function(cData){
                    if ( ! acceptedPoints[cData.ProjectName] ) { acceptedPoints[cData.ProjectName] = 0; }
                    acceptedPoints[cData.ProjectName] = cData.Accept;
                });
                summaryHash = {};
                _.each(projects, function(team) {
                    if (!summaryHash[team] && newHash[team]) {
                        summaryHash[team] = {
                            Name: team,
                            Count: newHash[team].length,
                            Days: 10,
                            Points: acceptedPoints[team],
                            Salary: "200,000",
                            Cost: 200000/newHash[team].length, 
                            ManDays: 0
                        };
                        if (acceptedPoints[team] > 0) {
                            summaryHash[team].ManDays = (10/acceptedPoints[team]) * newHash[team].length;
                        }
                    };
                });
                records = [];
                Ext.Object.each(summaryHash, function(key, value) {     
                    if (newHash[key]) {
                        records.push(value);
                    }   
                });
                this.records = records;
                var cfgsValues = [];
                var self = this;
                cfgsValues.push({text: 'Teams', style:"background-color: #D2EBC8", dataIndex: 'Name', width: 170, renderer: function(value, meta_data, record, row, col) {
                    return value;
                }});                    
                cfgsValues.push({text: '# Developers', style:"background-color: #D2EBC8", dataIndex: 'Count', width: 70, renderer: function(value, meta_data, record, row, col) {
                    self.Count = value;
                    return value;
                }});
                cfgsValues.push({text: '# Points', style:"background-color: #D2EBC8", dataIndex: 'Points', width: 70, renderer: function(value, meta_data, record, row, col) {
                    return value;
                }});                    
                cfgsValues.push({text: '# Days in Sprint', style:"background-color: #D2EBC8", dataIndex: 'Days', width: 70, renderer: function(value, meta_data, record, row, col) {
                    return value;
                }});
                cfgsValues.push(
                    {text: '# Average Salary Cost per Sprint', style:"background-color: #D2EBC8", dataIndex: 'Salary', width: 100, renderer: function(value, meta_data, record, row, col) {
                        self.value = value;
                        return "$" +value;
                    }, 
                    editor: {
                        xtype: 'textfield', // this assumes that salary is a number; if not, set to 'textfield'
                        listeners: {
                            click: {
                                element: 'el', //bind to the underlying el property on the panel
                                fn: function(){ 
                                    self.cost = self.value/self.Count;
                                    console.log('click el', self.value, self); 
                                    self._getSpan(self.cost);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });                     
                cfgsValues.push({text: '# Cost of 1 Story Point', style:"background-color: #D2EBC8", dataIndex: 'Cost', width: 100, renderer: function(value, meta_data, record, row, col) {
                    self.cost = value;
                    //return "$"+ Ext.Number.toFixed(value, 2);
                    return self._getSpan(record.raw.Cost);
                }});
                cfgsValues.push({text: '# man-days need per 1 Story Point', style:"background-color: #D2EBC8", dataIndex: 'ManDays', width: 100, renderer: function(value, meta_data, record, row, col) {
                    self.man_days = value;
                    return Ext.Number.toFixed(value, 2);
                }});                    
                this.setLoading(false);
                self.add({
                    xtype: 'rallygrid',
                    bodyBorder: 1,
                    id: 'mychart',
                    showPagingToolbar: false,
                    showRowActionsColumn: false,
                    enableEditing:true,
                    editable: true,
                    selType: 'cellmodel',
                    plugins: [
                        Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing', {
                            clicksToEdit: 2
                        })
                    ],                      
                    store: Ext.create('Rally.data.custom.Store', {
                        data: records
                    }),
                    columnCfgs: cfgsValues
                });             
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey found the way to do this

I just kept the `Cost` value `0` in the start

```
summaryHash[team] = {
    Name: team,
    Count: newHash[team].length,
    Days: 10,
    Points: acceptedPoints[team],
    Salary: "200000",
    Cost: 0, 
    ManDays: 0
};
```

And then made my `Salary` column editable

```
cfgsValues.push(
    {text: '# Average Salary Cost per Sprint', style:"background-color: #D2EBC8", dataIndex: 'Salary', width: 100, renderer: function(value, meta_data, record, row, col) {
        return "$" +value;
    }, 
    editor: {
        xtype: 'textfield', // this assumes that salary is a number; if not, set to 'textfield'
    }
});
```

And now whenever I edit the `Salary` value it changes `Cost` value

```
cfgsValues.push({text: '# Cost of 1 Story Point', style:"background-color: #D2EBC8", dataIndex: 'Cost', width: 100, renderer: function(value, meta_data, record, row, col) {
    return Ext.Number.toFixed(record.get('Salary')/record.get('Count'), 2);
}});
```